# How to expand/turn a view programmatically?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, perspective

I have a tableviewer with list of news titles, and when I click on a row, the news content view with browser is opened. But news page is too large and user should expand the news content view to see all it content. So I look for the way to expand a view programmatically.

[image: NewsContentView example]

I searched for the way in the Google and did not find anything. I looked the code of `org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/packageview/PackageExplorerPart.java` and did not find anything again. Then I realized, that expanding of a view should be implemented in more common way, by an extension point with actions or something similar. Then I remembered about `IWorkbenchPage.showView()`. I looked for the appropriate method and did not find such method. Expanding of a view should be implemented in something similar way, but I have no thoughts, what it could be.

Comment: You can maximize a view with all the other views being minimized, but other than that I don't know of a way to alter relative view sizes easily. You could switch to a different perspective with a larger area for the content view.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for your answer. I will try to minimize all other views. But behaviour, in which all existing views can be expanded on double-click, suggests that there is more easily way to maximize view.

Comment: Found another one workaround: if a view should be opened only on double-click on a row in table, add IFolderLayout with 0.95f ratio and placeholder with the view. But in this case view can not be minimized on double-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maximize a part using `IWorkbenchPage.toggleZoom`

For example the Maximize Part command handler does this:

```java
IWorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
if (activeWorkbenchWindow != null) {
    IWorkbenchPage page = activeWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage();
    if (page != null) {
        IWorkbenchPartReference partRef = page.getActivePartReference();
        if (partRef != null) {
            page.toggleZoom(partRef);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The view can not be minimized on double-click after `page.toggleZoom()`, but if add `page.zoomOut()`, then it can.

Comment: Could you please suggest, where did you find Maximize Part command handler?

Comment: `org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.MaximizePartHandler` in the org.eclipse.ui.workbench plugin

Answer (score 0):

Also there is the method `IWorkbenchPage.setPartState()` with using constants `IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MAXIMIZED`, `IWorkbenchPage.STATE_MINIMIZED` and `IWorkbenchPage.STATE_RESTORED`.